# What is Besicovitch projection theorem?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

This refers to the link https://arxiv.org/abs/0706.2646 I was looking for reference to understand Besicovitch projection theorem.  I could not understand the description of the theorem as given in the text. I am interested to know if there is any geometric interpretation of the theorem. Any more reference or some explanation like where it is applicable etc would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean beyond the paper you linked (Theorem 1.6) and the referenced [original paper by Besicovitch](https://eudml.org/doc/160004)?